# Unable to convert to timestamp using Kafka timestampconvert

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using Kafka source JDBC connector to pull DB events and I am running the kafka connect in standalone mode. When I run this file, I get the shown error. Please help me.

Code:

```
name=sailpointdb01107
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.password = xxxxx
connection.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521/xxxxx
connection.user =xxxxx 
query= SELECT * FROM (SELECT NAME, TO_TIMESTAMP('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD')+ NUMTODSINTERVAL(COMPLETED/1000,'SECOND') AS TASKFAILEDON FROM task WHERE COMPLETION_STATUS='Error')
mode= timestamp
timestamp.column.name=TASKFAILEDON
topic.prefix=testing
validate.non.null=false
transforms=TimestampConverter
transforms.TimestampConverter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.TimestampConverter.format=yyyy-MM-dd
transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type=Timestamp
transforms.TimestampConverter.target.field=TASKFAILEDON
```

Error:

```
Error[2019-10-01 15:17:45,058] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=sailpointdb01107-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Schema Schema{STRUCT} does not correspond to a known timestamp type format
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter.timestampTypeFromSchema(TimestampConverter.java:406)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter.applyWithSchema(TimestampConverter.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter.apply(TimestampConverter.java:275)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        ... 11 more
[2019-10-01 15:17:45,059] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=sailpointdb01107-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
```

Comment: Formatted code and error blocks to enhance readability and (possibly) impact. A few spelling/grammar corrections, too.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This line configured at connector could avoid that issue.

time.precision.mode: "connect"